# calling an interrupt vector inside an another interrupt vector

Tags: c, interrupt

Can I call an interrupt vector inside an another interrupt vector?

For example, while I'm doing a procedure in ep4inout interrupt vector:

```
void ep4inout interrupt 0
{
   .
   .
   .
   Timer1 = 1; //call interrupt for timer 1
   .
   .
   .
}
```

**Edit**

My code looks roughly like this. Timer1 = 1, means the interrupt request for timer 1 is set. My procedure in Timer 1 ISR is not working. In the manual for FX2LP, timer 1 have a higher priority than Endpoint buffers. I tried setting the priority of Timer 1 to high and Endpoint 4 to low. Still the same result. Im using Keil uVision2 as my IDE and my microcontroller is Cypress FX2LP(enchanced 8051 - USB controller).

```
void ISR_Ep4inout(void) interrupt 0
{
   .
   .
   .
   Timer1Enable = 1;
   Timer1 = 1; //call interrupt for timer 1
   .
   .
   .
}

void TMR1_Vect(void) interrupt 2 //timer 1 interrupt
{
 .
 .
 .
}

void TMR1_Vect interrupt 0 //timer 1 interrupt
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are regular C functions, the compiler cannot know that the function is used as an interrupt. Yes, you may call that function.

If, as in your case, you have to indicate such functions using `interrupt 0` or any other means (`ISR`, `INTERRUPT`), you normally cannot.
The problem often is the `return` instruction (on assembler level) used to terminate the function: For an interrupt service routine the compiler has to use a different return-instruction.

You have indicated a different method for "calling a function": I assume your `Timer1 = 1;` will effectively set the interrupt request bit for the timer interrupt, resulting in activation of the interrupt service routine. This should be no problem whatsoever. But you need to check the processor/compiler manuals about which interrupt is handled first, and if ISRs are being interrupted.

BTW, you could have provided more information and details. Not everyone speaks of "calling an interrupt vector" and then shows a 'variable' being set to one. I assume you're into embedded development; please indicate things like compiler and/or processor, since they are more than relevant for providing a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Im using Keil uVision 2 and my micro-controller is a Cypress FX2LP. After testing the ISR for timer 1 is not interrupted my procedure is not working at all. Timer 1 means that the interrupt for timer 1 has been called. BTW, what is the priority of endpoint 4?

Comment: @FranzMationg It would be better if you edit your original question and add this information there. The site is intended to be useful not only for you but for all who have the same or a similar question. In addition, for those not too familiar with the Cypress USB controller family, it would be helpful to state that the processor is an enhanced 8051 implementation.